# Jenkins test gives error: the driver executable does not exists

Tags: eclipse, selenium, jenkins

I'm trying to run my test using Jenkins with Mac os.I use very simple code which is basically to open google.com. When I run it in eclipse it is successful, this is my code:

```
package GitProject.gittest;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.AssertJUnit;

/**
* Unit test for simple App.
*/
public class AppTest
{

@Test
public void testApp()
{
    String exePath = "/Users/enislavmollov/Downloads/chromedriver";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", exePath);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("http://google.com");

    System.out.println("Success");

    driver.quit();
}
}
```

The pom.xml is positioned in Jenkins' workspace, otherwise it gives me error. When I run it from Jenkins my build fails and it gives me error:

```
Failed

GitProject.gittest.AppTest.testApp


Error Message

The driver executable does not exist: 
/Users/enislavmollov/Downloads/chromedriver
Stacktrace

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /Users/enislavmollov/Downloads/chromedriver
```

Comment: are you running the jenkins server on the same machine where your script are there?

Comment: yes, they are on one machine. Jenkins is on /Users/Shared/Jenkins and Selenium scripts on /Users/enislavmollov/Documents/workspace

Comment: is driver accessible by jenkins? may be the access permission problem. please check it for the driver.

Comment: yes, it is. The only way to make it work is to change destination of chromedriver to Jenkins workspace

Comment: yes if you move it to workspace, it will work.

Comment: Ok but why I have to move it same thing is with the pom.xml/ The only way was to copy it to workspace of Jenkins project?

Comment: yes you can copy it as well.